# Convert a long format to wide

Tags: r, function, reshape, reshape2

My data frame looks like this:

```
 x <- data.frame(c("a","a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c","a", "a"), c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3, 1, 2))
names(x) <- c("id","nr") 

      id      nr
   1   a       1
   2   a       2
   3   a       3
   4   a       4
   5   b       1
   6   b       2
   7   c       1
   8   c       2
   9   c       3
   10  a       1
   11  a       2
```

I want to have something like this:

```
  id   1  2  3  4
   a   1  2  3  4
   a   1  2  NA NA
   b   1  2  NA NA
   c   1  2  3  NA
```

I already used `dcast(x, id ~ nr, value.var ="nr")` but I got the warning:

> "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length".

I understand that this is due to non-unique rows. Also I created groups which give me the results above. But is there a way to create it without having to create groups?

```
x <- data.frame(c("a","a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c","a", "a"), 
c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2), c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3, 1, 2))
names(x) <- c("id", "group","nr")

dcast(x, id + group ~ nr, value.var = "nr")
```

Comment: What's the question? The warning happens because you don't specify argument fun.aggregate . .

Comment: oh yes, i see - for every id value , OP wants a new row for unique combinations of NR values..

Comment: Related: [*dcast error: ‘Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length’*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33051386/2204410)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need a grouping variable.  Instead of creating it manually as showed in the example, we can use `rleid` and then try with `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table`. i.e. `v1.9.5+`.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(x)[, gr:=rleid(id)], id+gr~nr, value.var='nr')[,gr:=NULL][]
#   id 1 2  3  4
#1:  a 1 2  3  4
#2:  a 1 2 NA NA
#3:  b 1 2 NA NA
#4:  c 1 2  3 NA
```

Or as @Arun mentioned in the comments, we can do this directly within the `dcast` itself

```
dcast(setDT(x), id + rleid(id) ~ nr, value.var = 'nr')[,id_1:= NULL]
```

Comment: @Arun Thanks, that is more compact and avoids the creations/removal of column