# dcast warning: ‘Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length’

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, reshape2

My `df` looks like this:

```
Id  Task Type    Freq  
3     1    A       2
3     1    B       3
3     2    A       3
3     2    B       0
4     1    A       3
4     1    B       3
4     2    A       1
4     2    B       3
```

I want to restructure by Id and get:

```
Id   A    B …  Z    
3    5    3      
4    4    6
```

I tried:

```
df_wide <- dcast(df, Id + Task ~ Type, value.var="Freq")
```

and got the following warning:

> Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length

I can't figure out what to put in the `fun.aggregate`. What's the problem?

Comment: Based on the example showed, I am not getting any warnings.  If you have duplicates, then you may need to create a sequence column

Comment: If you need the `sum` (based on the expected output showed) `dcast(df, Id~Type, value.var='Freq', sum)`

Comment: Thanks Jaap! I'm not sure that I fully understand your explanation: My first two columns (Id and Task) need to collapse from two rows to one. Is this why I need the fun.aggregate function? And if so - why "sum"? I'm not summing them.

Comment: Could you specify when you get the warning message? With `dcast(df, Id ~ Type, value.var="Freq")` or with `dcast(df, Id + Task ~ Type, value.var="Freq")`? I'm only getting a warning when using `dcast(df, Id ~ Type, value.var="Freq")` (which is logical as I asexplained in my answer).

Comment: I'm getting it when I use 'dcast(df, Id + Task ~ Type, value.var="Freq")'.

Answer (score 39):

The reason why you are getting this warning is in the description of `fun.aggregate` (see `?dcast`):

> aggregation function needed if variables do not identify a single
> observation for each output cell. Defaults to length (with a message)
> if needed but not specified

So, an aggregation function is needed when there is more than one value for one spot in the wide dataframe.

***An explanation based on your data:***

When you use `dcast(df, Id + Task ~ Type, value.var="Freq")` you get:

```
  Id Task A B
1  3    1 2 3
2  3    2 3 0
3  4    1 3 3
4  4    2 1 3
```

Which is logical because for each combination of `Id`, `Task` and `Type` there is only one value in `Freq`. But when you use `dcast(df, Id ~ Type, value.var="Freq")` you get this (including a warning message):

```
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
  Id A B
1  3 2 2
2  4 2 2
```

Now, looking back at the top part of your data:

```
Id  Task Type    Freq  
3     1    A       2
3     1    B       3
3     2    A       3
3     2    B       0
```

You see why this is the case. For each combination of `Id` and `Type` there are two values in `Freq` (for Id 3: `2` and `3` for `A` & `3` and `0` for Type `B`) while you can only put one value in this spot in the wide dataframe for each values of `type`. Therefore `dcast` wants to aggregate these values into one value. The default aggregation function is `length`, but you can use other aggregation functions like `sum`, `mean`, `sd` or a custom function by specifying them with `fun.aggregate`.

For example, with `fun.aggregate = sum` you get:

```
  Id A B
1  3 5 3
2  4 4 6
```

Now there is no warning because `dcast` is being told what to do when there is more than one value: return the sum of the values.

Comment: Nice explanation. How do you aggregate this for say characters?

Comment: @NelsonGon For characters you use for example use the `toString`-function to aggregate them: `dcast(df, Id ~ Type, value.var="Freq", fun.aggregate = toString)`. Alternatively you can define your own aggregation function - e.g.: `f.agg <- function(x) paste(x, collapse = "-")` - and use that: `dcast(df, Id ~ Type, value.var="Freq", fun.aggregate = f.agg)`

Comment: But do you know how "length" works? I mean what does ``fun.aggregate = length`` do? I think I get this warning because of duplicate values from daylight saving.

Comment: @PeyM87 it counts the values by group

Answer (score 0):

`fun.aggregate` is required when different values *inside* `value.var` column corresponding to *identical* values - or combination of values - appearing on the LHS of `dcast` formula (e.g. "Id"), are forced into one cell by the combination of variables in the RHS of the formula (e.g. "Type").

Defaulting to `length()` in `dcast` is informative as it

- could suggest existence of coupling in the data, and
- locates `length > 1` cases that may require attention.

More informative would be using function `list()` as `fun.aggregate` since it shows which `value.var` values are involved in each case:

```
dcast(dt, Id ~ Type, fun.aggregate = list, value.var = 'Freq')

   Id   A   B
1:  3 2,3 3,0
2:  4 3,1 3,3
```

Basically, table cells have length = 1. Therefore, the defaulting situation in `dcast` can be solved by modifying the formula or, by implementing a length-one summarization (aggregation): operators, custom or available functions that give a length-one result in each case and are fit for the purpose.

Comment: This is basically the same as my answer. So, why post again?