# Equivalent of two table() functions in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column with two variables that I would like to count occurrences of by date.

```
> testData
   plan_type       date
1 subscriber 2016-09-06
2 subscriber 2017-01-19
3 subscriber 2016-10-07
4        PPU 2017-01-19
5        PPU 2015-06-17
6        PPU 2015-07-03
```

I know that this can be done for example by subsetting into two different dataframes - one with only `subscriber` and one with only `PPU` data, then use `table()` and bind the two dataframes together. But I'd like to find a more efficient solution with `dplyr` that can do this in one command.

The output should look something like this, with NA values where there is no data for one of the variables.

```
> output 
        date subscriber  PPU
1 2015-06-17       <NA>    1
2 2015-07-03       <NA>    1
3 2016-09-06          1 <NA>
4 2016-10-07          1 <NA>
5 2017-01-19          1    1
```

Is there a specific formula that would perform this function in `dplyr`?

Comment: `reshape2::dcast(testData, date ~ plan_type, length)`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417973/easy-way-to-convert-long-to-wide-format-with-counts/34418124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can create a new costant columns `n` and then `spread()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
    mutate(n = 1) %>% 
    spread(plan_type, n)

#>         date PPU subscriber
#> 1 2015-06-17   1         NA
#> 2 2015-07-03   1         NA
#> 3 2016-09-06  NA          1
#> 4 2016-10-07  NA          1
#> 5 2017-01-19   1          1
```

Data:

```r
df <- read.table(text = '   plan_type       date
                 1 subscriber 2016-09-06
                 2 subscriber 2017-01-19
                 3 subscriber 2016-10-07
                 4        PPU 2017-01-19
                 5        PPU 2015-06-17
                 6        PPU 2015-07-03', header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table` we can use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), date~plan_type, length)
#         date PPU subscriber
#1: 2015-06-17   1          0
#2: 2015-07-03   1          0
#3: 2016-09-06   0          1
#4: 2016-10-07   0          1
#5: 2017-01-19   1          1
```