# Coerce column values to column names and condense repeat observations in R

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:
CLAIM   CODE
a 1
a 2
a       3
b       1
b       2
c       3

And i want this dataframe:

CLAIM    CODE1     CODE2     CODE3
a          1        1          1
b          1        1          0
c          0        0          1

one-hot encoding either encodes the both columns or removes the encoded column from the original dataset.  I've also tried spread() but it doesn't quite get me all the way to my target dataframe

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect the structure of your dataframe (columns / rows) and of the expected output. As it is, we can see what is columns and what is rows

Comment: The question is not clear, I do not understand how rows and columns are supposed to match

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy way to convert long to wide format with counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417973/easy-way-to-convert-long-to-wide-format-with-counts)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `table` from `base R`

```
table(df1)
#  CODE
#CLAIM 1 2 3
#    a 1 1 1
#    b 1 1 0
#    c 0 0 1
```

Comment: Now that I see the solution, I better understand the question ;)