# How can I cast a data frame with two related columns?

Tags: r, reshape2, dcast

I have a data frame that looks like the following.

```
"id" "question" "response"  "suite"
1    "x"        "a"         "1"
2    "y"        "b"         "1"
3    "x"        "c"         "1"
4    "y"        "d"         "1"
5    "x"        "e"         "2"
6    "y"        "f"         "2"
```

Dcast (in reshape2) seems my best bet so far to do this in one line.

```
result <- dcast(df, id + suite ~ question, value.var = "response")
```

Though I end up with this;

```
"id" "suite" "x" "y"
1    "1"     "1" "1"
2    "1"     "1" "1"
3    "1"     "1" "1"
4    "1"     "1" "1"
5    "2"     "1" "1"
6    "2"     "1" "1"
```

Along with the error;

```
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length(response)
```

How can I get that second format without losing my strings in the "response" column?

Comment: What is the desired outcome? A possibility is to use `fun.aggregate = toString` to get the values in a string format.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: btw: it is a warning, not an error; [see here for an explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33051521/2204410)

Comment: `fun.aggregate = toString` @ProcrastinatusMaximus that's the one. Nice simple fix. Thanks!