# Turn long dataset of classes taken into wide dataset where variables are dummy code for each class

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, reshape2

Say I have a dataset where rows are classes people took:

```
attendance <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                         class = c("Math", "English", "Math", "Reading", "Math"))  

I.e.,

     id  class  
   1 1   "Math" 
   2 1   "English"
   3 1   "Math"
   4 2   "Reading"
   5 2   "Math"
```

And I want to create a new dataset where rows are ids and the variables are class names, like this:

```
class.names <- names(table(attendance$class))
attedance2 <-  matrix(nrow=length(table(attendance$id)), 
                      ncol=length(class.names)) 
colnames(attedance2) <- class.names
attedance2 <- as.data.frame(attedance2)
attedance2$id <- unique(attendance$id)

I.e.,

     English  Math  Reading  id
   1    NA     NA      NA     1
   2    NA     NA      NA     2
```

I want to fill in the NAs with whether that particular id took that class or not. It can be Yes/No, 1/0, or counts of the classes

```
I.e.,

     English  Math  Reading  id
   1   "Yes"  "Yes"   "No"    1
   2   "No"   "Yes"   "Yes"   2
```

I'm familiar with dplyr, so it'd be easier for me if that was used in the solution but not necessary. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Essentially just `table(unique(attendance))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
library(reshape2)
attendance$val <- 'yes'
dcast(unique(attendance), id ~ class, value.var = 'val', fill = 'no')
```

gives:

> ```
>   id English Math Reading
> 1  1     yes  yes      no
> 2  2      no  yes     yes
> ```

A similar approach with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(unique(setDT(attendance))[,val:='yes'], id ~ class, value.var = 'val', fill = 'no')
```

Or with `dplyr`/`tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
attendance %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(var = 'yes') %>% 
  spread(class, var, fill = 'no')
```

---

Another, somewhat more convoluted option might to reshape first and then replace the counts with `yes` and `no` (see [here for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33051521/2204410) about the default aggregate option of `dcast`):

```
 att2 <- dcast(attendance, id ~ class, value.var = 'class')
```

which gives:

> ```
>   id English Math Reading
> 1  1       1    2       0
> 2  2       0    1       1
> ```

Now you can replace the count with:

```
# create index which counts are above zero
idx <- att2[,-1] > 0
# replace the non-zero values with 'yes'
att2[,-1][idx] <- 'yes'
# replace the zero values with 'no'
att2[,-1][!idx] <- 'no'
```

which finally gives:

> ```
> > att2
>   id English Math Reading
> 1  1     yes  yes      no
> 2  2      no  yes     yes
> ```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `base R`

```
attendance$val <- "yes"
d1 <- reshape(attendance, idvar = 'id', direction = 'wide', timevar = 'class')
d1[is.na(d1)] <- "no"
names(d1) <- sub("val\\.", '', names(d1))
d1
#  id Math English Reading
#1  1  yes     yes      no
#4  2  yes      no     yes
```

---

Or with `xtabs`

```
xtabs(val ~id + class, transform(unique(attendance), val = 1))
#    class
# id  English Math Reading
#  1       1    1       0
#  2       0    1       1
```

NOTE: The binary can be easily converted to 'yes', 'no', but it is better to have either 1/0 or `TRUE/FALSE`